# I am trying to run my schedule command on AWS but not working

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon web services and i am trying to run my schedule command every five minutes on server but unfortunately it's not working but when i run my schedule directly on terminal it's working perfectly please help me how can i resolve that ? thank u

this my project directory here.

/var/www/html

this is command

```
 * * * * * cd /var/www/html/ && artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**/var/www/html/app/Console**

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('booking:cron')->everyFiveMinutes();

    }
```

**/var/www/html/app/Console/Commands**

```
 public function handle()
    {
        \DB::table('bookings')
        ->where('booking_reservation_status',0)
        ->update(['booking_holding_status'=> '0']);


        info('updated');
    }
```

[image]

Comment: the command from the screenshot is missing '/' before var

Comment: sir  i am facing same issue.

Comment: Can you check the syslogs using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: please check  CRON[146889]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/se                 ssionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean;